# Page not rendering because of url

Tags: django

I want to make contact page is made of simple template html.

in view.py i made this

```
 from .models import tutorials
 from django.views import generic

 class Contactviews(generic.View):
 template_name = 'home/contact.html'
```

and this is my url:

```
url(r'^contact$',views.Contactviews.as_view(), name='contact')
```

the contact.html is just a simple text that extends from base.html .and it doesnt involve any functionality from models.py

so the page is not rendering.

i think maybe problem is on my url address.

Comment: What *does* happen? errors?

Comment: it was blank page .so i check the address in pycharm with ctrl+left click .and saw that the django cant find my contact.html.i changed the class view to generic.Listview and it worked.i dont know why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The base View class doesn't know anything about templates. You should use TemplateView.

Comment: Yeah i find that .im new tnx for helping me